# 20.04 point release - no update yet from gb.archive?

Tags: updates, 20.04

Over the past 4 years I have had 2 successful automatic updates for LTS versions. My settings are for notification for long-term support versions of Ubuntu to be available. I check for updates from gb.archive.ubuntu.com. Despite the first point release being slated for 6th August, I don't get prompted for its availability amongst my updates, today 11th August. Should I be concerned?

Comment: No, it doesn't answer my question. I asked that question 2 years ago, when there was a known problem with the update process. I was hoping that some kind soul might say that they too could get nothing from the gb..archive, or otherwise. As usual, I get is sniping and a vote to close.

Comment: I use the Australian mirror, and no upgrades have been offered for *bionic* systems.  There have been numerous minor issues (Qt4 & python2 have reached EOL, thus packages removed from repos, ROS issues etc) and I've seen an issue by N0bert (on launchpad, but a user here) that may be somewhat significant .. but currently the *taps* haven't been turned. A *how-to* force was published by the Ubuntu Release Team.

Comment: "*Users of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS will soon be offered an automatic upgrade to 20.04.1 LTS via Update Manager. For further information about upgrading...*"  http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/06/ubuntu-20-04-1-lts-released/  (that is just ML release notes published on Ubuntu Fridge (*an annoucement board for people that don't like mailing lists representing a noticeboard on a company fridge*)   The delay is to ensure **stability** for LTS users, so you should **not** be worried,

Comment: Thank you for that information, it's helpful.

Comment: It could also be that the mirrors you're using aren't yet in sync. These sort of things get rolled out in waves, so as to avoid all users hammering on the bandwidth on a single day. You can actually see if your mirrors are behind or in sync from [this link](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors).